# How to choose a fuzzy matching algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, fuzzy-comparison

I need to know the criteria which made fuzzy algo different from each other between those 3 :

**Levenshtein distance Algorithm**

*Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the difference between two sequences. Informally, the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (i.e. insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other.*

**Damerau–Levenshtein distance**

*Damerau–Levenshtein distance is a distance (string metric) between two strings, i.e., finite sequence of symbols, given by counting the minimum number of operations needed to transform one string into the other, where an operation is defined as an insertion, deletion, or substitution of a single character, or a transposition of two adjacent characters.*

**Bitap algorithm with modifications by Wu and Manber**

*Bitmap algorithm is an approximate string matching algorithm. The algorithm tells whether a given text contains a substring which is "approximately equal" to a given pattern, where approximate equality is defined in terms of Levenshtein distance — if the substring and pattern are within a given distance k of each other, then the algorithm considers them equal.*

**My document is a table with name of companies, some companies are twice or three time because of misspelling. In this particular case, how to group the companies by matching them ? Which algorithm to chose and why ? In the file I have 100k lines and it is growing.**

Comment: Hello, what have you tried ? Perhaps it would be best to start with the most complex of the algorithms and downgrade if it doesn't do what you like. Maybe somebody on the web had the same question, have you checked ?

Comment: @reportgunner I would do it the other way, start with the less complex and upgrade, if it does not work. Also, PHP offers the levenshtein methods: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: Thanks, why to use PHP ? I thought Python was best way (for huge amount of data, ML and other libraries....)

Comment: It does not really matter. An automatic search with fuzzy distance between strings will allways have non detection and false positives. Because a human being will know that 'SNCF' and 'Société nationale des chemins de fer' are of course the same company, but a distance based algo will have a hard time to say the same. On the other side, 'General Mechanics of London' and 'General Mechanics of Londoderry' are likely to be different companies (just a forged example here).

Comment: @TTeaTie: Googling for *python levenshtein* gives enough results, so  you can use Python if you know it better than PHP.

Comment: DL extends L with swaps of adjacent letters. Bitap is an approximate L. I tend to go to the q-gram filtration approximation of L as it is simple and fast.

Comment: Serge okay merci. @DanD. so i can use Bitap to have my algorithm to find more similar companies ? I need a 80% accuracy on matching.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Google Sheets, try using [Flookup](https://www.getflookup.com). You say that your list has over 100K rows so that might prove a bit of a challenge depending on Google's (timed) execution limits but I still encourage you to give it a try.
One function you might be interested in is:

```
FLOOKUP(lookupValue, tableArray, lookupCol, indexNum, [threshold], [rank])
```

**Full Disclosure:** I created Flookup for Google sheets

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group the companies you could use locality sensitive hashing or a clustering method such as K-medoids clustering with e.g., Levenshtein edit distance as the metric. Alternatively, you can use [SymSpell](https://github.com/wolfgarbe/SymSpell).

Levenshtein- and Damerau–Levenshtein distance are both good metrics for string similarity, but make sure that you use a fast implementation. There are too many popular and insanely slow implementations on Github. The best I know of are [PolyLeven](https://github.com/fujimotos/polyleven) or [editdistance](https://github.com/aflc/editdistance).